# Prevent Document Window Document Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say that we have a Javascript Function that calls an external JS file, like so:

```
(window,document,'script','www.mydomain.com/myscript.js');
```

How we can prevent that (or even remove somehow the call - remove the URL) from it, with Javascript?

I was trying to find the domain 'www.mydomain.com' and remove it, but I couldn't get access to the elements inside script tag.

Comment: _Lets say that we have a Javascript Function that calls an external JS file_ Remove that line from your function

Comment: "...from it, with Javascript"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP). CSP allows you to block / whitelist any external resources loaded in your website/user's browser.

> Content Security Policy (CSP) is an added layer of security that helps to detect and mitigate certain types of attacks, including Cross Site Scripting (XSS) and data injection attacks. These attacks are used for everything from data theft to site defacement or distribution of malware.
>
> A primary goal of CSP is to mitigate and report XSS attacks. XSS attacks exploit the browser's trust of the content received from the server. Malicious scripts are executed by the victim's browser because the browser trusts the source of the content, even when it's not coming from where it seems to be coming from.

Comment: thank you! Do you know how I can prevent a specific domain like "mydomain.com"? Im trying with 'script-src 'none' mydomain.com', but all scripts are cut off.